# R markdown to PDF preserve (leading) whitespace

Tags: pdf, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I have an R markdown file that I want to convert to PDF using knitr (or sweave).

For example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{python}
for x in range(3):
  for y in range(3):
    print(x+y)
```
````

If I knit to PDF and copy paste the for loop part back to a text editor, the tabs are gone. This is certainly expected behaviour considering how anti whitespace-preservation markdown and pdf are, but can I still somehow preserve the actual whitespace characters when knitting from R markdown to PDF?

Comment: I think this has mostly to do with how your PDF-viewer handles copying whitespace... you can see the whitespaces in the PDF, right?

Comment: Yes, I can see the whitespace in PDF. And I think you're absolutely correct. I read a bunch on the topic yesterday and today and the conclusion I'm coming to is that if the pdf looks right, it is right. Meaning there's nothing I can do in markdown or latex to make sure anyone can copy all the whitespace correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, there's nothing that can be done other than making sure the document looks right, i.e. visually the whitespace is there.

It comes down to what the PDF format actually is, read the accepted answer to this question - https://superuser.com/questions/198392/how-to-copy-text-out-of-a-pdf-without-losing-formatting